# Adding solutions as constraints to enumerate solutions to a linear programming p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: enumeration, linear-programming

I've managed to model a problem as an LP problem with binary variables and solve it (using PuLP and GLPK). I believe that I read somewhere that you can "add your solution as a new constraint" to get the solver to come up with an alternative solution. Unfortunately I can't find where I read this, and I can't see how to "add the solution" to prevent the solver coming up with the previous solution. If what I read is correct, can someone explain how to do this please?

I am very new to LP. I have searched for an answer but it is likely I failed because I don't know the right search terms. I do know that in general enumerating the solution space isn't feasible because of the very large size of the space. I am simply interested in knowing how to "add a solution" to prevent the solver finding it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An LP with binary variables is no longer an LP (but rather a MIP). A constraint to forbid a previously found integer solution `x*(i)` can be formulated as follows.

- Let `P subset of I` be the set corresponding to indices where `x*(i)=1`.
- Let `Q subset of I` be the set corresponding to indices where `x*(i)=0`.

Obviously `P+Q=I`. Add to the model the following constraint:

`sum(i in P, x(i)) - sum(i in Q, x(i)) <= p - 1`

where `p` is the cardinality (number of elements) of set `P`. The derivation of this constraint is [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2011/10/integer-cuts.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could add an objective cutoff to your problem that will make your previous solution infeasible, but this will most likely cut off other solutions as well - especially for degenerate problems.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682209/getting-all-solutions-in-google-or-tools) is a closely related question, that might be helpful. See my answer there for an idea on how to add an objective cutoff.